# Create counting class extending Hashset / Inheritance

Tags: java, collections, hashset

If we consider the following class to count object added in an HashSet :

```
public class CountingHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {

    public int addCount = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
     addCount +=1;
     return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? 
    extends E> c) {
     addCount += c.size();
     return super.addAll(c);
    }
```

}

Then, the JUnit test failed :

```
@Test
public void testCount() {
    CountingHashSet<Integer> s = new CountingHashSet<>();
         s.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    for (int i = 6; i <= 10; ++i)
        s.add(i);
 assertEquals(10, s.addCount);
}
```

I get the following :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<10> but was <15>
```

Why I get 15 ? To my mind `s.addAll(myCollection)` call `super.addAll(c)` and if I look into the source code of `hashSet`, I saw that `addAll(c)` call `add(e)` to add each element. But why `super.addAll(c)` call the `add method` that I redefined ? (that's why I get 15 instead of 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're treating inheritance as if it were composition. It's not. The calls don't end up being "`add()` on the `HashSet`" - they end up being "`add()` on the current object".

> But why super.addAll(c) call the add method that I redefined ?

Because that's how virtual methods behave. `addAll` just calls `add()`, which will use the most overridden implementation in the actual type. That's how polymorphism *always* works. Let's write a simpler example:

```
class Superclass {
    public void foo() {
        bar();
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("Superclass.bar()");
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("Subclass.bar()");
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Superclass x = new Subclass();
        x.foo(); // Prints Subclass.bar()
    }
}
```

Is the result of `Subclass.bar()` what you'd expect from this example? If so, what do you expect the difference would be in your version? Just because you're calling `super.addAll()` doesn't mean that the object is suddenly in "non-overriding" mode or anything like that.

Comment: Ok, it's clearer now. But the fact that `addAll` uses `add` is a detail of internal implementation of the class which would have no effects from the outside. So, I think that this shows possible situations that inheritance can be a problem right ? (it breaks encapsulation)

Comment: @user2336315: Well, it's documented in `AbstractCollection`. But yes, the way that inheritance makes things which would *otherwise* be pure implementation details leak into the documented API is definitely a problem of inheritance IMO, and is one reason I prefer composition :)

Comment: This is _exactly_ the example used by Effective Java to show why composition is preferable to inheritance, right down to the variable names.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I saw this in class, I didn't know it was in a book

Answer (score 1):

That's how polymorphism works. Your object is of type `CountingHashSet`, so a call to `add` will call `CountingHashSet.add`, even from the super type.